# selecting single record if multiple records are having same length

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to solve [this problem on HackerRank](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/weather-observation-station-5)

I tried this query :

```
select city, length(city) from station 
where length(city) = (select max(length(city)) from station)
      or length(city) = (select min(length(city)) from station)
order by
length(city) ASC,city ASC;
```

After running the above query, I get the following result :

```
Amo 3 
Lee 3 
Roy 3 
Marine On Saint Croix 21
```

My Problem is : I only want to select `Amo` & `Marine On Saint Croix`. Not others.
How to achieve this ?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: `where city in ('amo', 'marine')`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the correct query that works:

```
 (SELECT city, LENGTH(city) AS length FROM station
ORDER BY LENGTH(city), city
LIMIT 1) UNION 

(SELECT city, LENGTH(city) AS length FROM station
ORDER BY LENGTH(city) DESC, city
LIMIT 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try selecting both min and max length cities with limit 1 and union it?

```
select city, length(city) from station 
where  length(city) = (select max(length(city)) from station)
Limit  1
UNION
select city, length(city) from station 
where  length(city) = (select min(length(city)) from station)
Limit  1
```

Comment: It ain't working @Deepak Pawar. Only one record is being selected.